# Why isn't my UILabel subview of a UIView not displaying?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

This feels like some variant on this question must have been asked and answered, but I cannot find it.

I am finally biting the bullet and moving from storyboards to programmatically created view hierarchies, but am hitting a snag.  In the view controller's viewDidLoad() I am successfully adding a subview, which I keep a reference to in the variable managedView.  Immediately after that (in the same viewDidLoad), I am attempting to add a UILabel as a subview for managedView.  But the label does not appear.  No error message, no failure, no label...

I have used the view debugger and confirmed that it is not a case that the label exists but is invisible or off screen.  It's not in the view hierarchy.

What am I missing?

Here is the code in viewDidLoad

```
  override func viewDidLoad()
  {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = .clear

    managedView = UIView()
    view.addSubview(managedView)
    managedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    managedView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    managedView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    managedView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    managedView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    managedView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    managedView.alignCenter(to: view)
    managedView.minSize(width:200.0, height:200.0)

    let titleView:UILabel =
    {
      let v = UILabel()
      v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      v.text = title ?? "???"
      v.font = Style.titleFont
      v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
      v.textColor = UIColor.label
      return v
    }()
    managedView.addSubview(titleView)
    titleView.anchorTop(to: managedView,offset: Style.edgeMargin)
    titleView.constrainSize(width:150.0, height:15.0)
    titleView.alignCenterX(to: managedView)
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Note that I extended UIView to provide simpler named auto layout constraint methods. The following is the code for the constraint methods used above:

```
extension UIView
{
  ...

  func alignCenterX(to otherView:UIView, offset:CGFloat = 0.0)
  {
    self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.centerXAnchor, constant: offset).isActive = true
  }

  ...

  func anchorTop(to otherView:UIView, offset:CGFloat = 0.0)
  {
    self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.bottomAnchor, constant: offset).isActive = true
  }

  ...

  func alignCenterY(to otherView:UIView, offset:CGFloat = 0.0)
  {
    self.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.centerYAnchor, constant: offset).isActive = true
  }

  ...

  func constrainWidth(_ width:CGFloat)
  {
    self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true
  }
  func constrainHeight(_ height:CGFloat)
  {
    self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true
  }

  ...

  func minWidth(_ width:CGFloat)
  {
    self.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: width).isActive = true
  }

  func minHeight(_ height:CGFloat)
  {
    self.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: height).isActive = true
  }

  ...

  func alignCenter(to otherView:UIView)
  {
    alignCenterY(to: otherView)
    alignCenterX(to: otherView)
  }

  func minSize(width:CGFloat,height:CGFloat)
  {
    self.minWidth(width)
    self.minHeight(height)
  }

}
```

Comment: where is `constrainSize` ?

Comment: have you added any constraints to `managedView`  other than `minSize` ?

Comment: Doh... accidentally trimmed that out when asking the question.
constrainSize() is just a wrapper around constrainWidth() and constrainHeight()

Comment: The alignCenter(to:view) adds constraints to equate the managed view's centerXAnchor and centerYanchor to view's centerXAnchor and centerYanchor respectively.

Comment: i got it ... expecting that :) ... have you added any constraints to managedView other than minSize ? what about this one ?

Comment: I'm sorry... I'm feeling dense.  "what about this one?" refers to what?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this!  I do appreciate it.  DonMag hit the problem on the head.  I had used the wrong constraint wrapper.  Should have used alignTop rather than attachTop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem with using "constraint helpers" ... we sometimes don't know what's really going on.

Your extension has this:

```
func anchorTop(to otherView:UIView, offset:CGFloat = 0.0)
{
    self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.bottomAnchor, constant: offset).isActive = true
}
```

And you are calling

```
titleView.anchorTop(to: managedView,offset: Style.edgeMargin)
```

Which means:

```
set the TOP of titleLabel to the BOTTOM of managedView + Style.edgeMargin
```

If you change your `anchorTop` to this:

```
func anchorTop(to otherView:UIView, offset:CGFloat = 0.0)
{
    self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.topAnchor, constant: offset).isActive = true
}
```

You will see your label, at `Style.edgeMargin` pts below the TOP of managedView... but, that will change your layout anywhere else you're using `anchorTop()`.

Comment: Thank you!!!  That was it.  I meant to use alignTop() function rather than anchorTop()... which does exactly what you suggested.

Comment: @MikeMayer67 - by the way... if you had looked a bit closer in `Debug View Hierarchy` you would have seen that your label **was** in the hierarchy, but was outside the bounds of its superview. Also, your `minSize()` helper leaves ambiguity.

Comment: I am aware of the ambiguity.  The setup is not complete.  In the end, I will remove the minSize constraint once I have fully populated the managedView and setup all of the constraints so that the view will fit to its content.  I addedthe minSize temporarily to demo the issue.   Also, I decided to rename the anchorTop, anchorBottom, anchorLeft, and anchorRight methods to attachTop, attachBottom, etc. to avoid reduce the chance of repeating this same layout error.